# How to get whats inside a variable ID or Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

Say I have this:

```
var name = $('#contactName');
```

Is there a way to get just the `contactName` out of that variable?

Edit: The variable is already set and the value of it is `$('#contactName')`.

What I want to do is retrieve the text from that variable, not create multiple variables. I could easily duplicate variables and just do `var nameID = 'contactName'` but I am hoping theres an alternative.

Comment: Example html please; It's not clear what you mean.

Comment: Post edit, that still makes no sense.

Comment: `$('#contactName')` is a **function call**, the value of `name` is the **return value** of that function call, not the call itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `selector` property:

```
var name = $('#contactName');
alert(name.selector); // alerts #contactName
```

However, you'd have to strip the `#`, so something like:

```
s.selector.replace('#','')
```

Obviously, this would only work for ID-based or tag-based selectors.  Class-based selectors would need the `.` removing.

Comment: @tfbox: try making your questions clearer to begin with and 'someone will understand' sooner...

Comment: Confused... doesn't `$('#contactName').attr('id')` (as @benlumley suggested) return the same same thing with the `#` *already* stripped?

Comment: surely `alert(name.attr('id'))`

Comment: @tfbox: I wouldn't go as far as to say I _understand_... I was making the assumption you might have other selectors for which you wanted the text.  If that's not the case and you just want the ID of the selected element then I don't see anything wrong with @benlumley's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var name = $('#contactName').attr('id');
```

Comment: Not sure you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Maybe not ... can you explain a bit more?

Comment: +1 for actually (it transpires) understanding perfectly well! ;)

Answer (score 1):

All jQuery objects have a `selector` property that will return the selector they were created with, so your `name` object would return `#contactName`. You could then strip off the hash sign.

Answer (score 0):

The title and body of your question seem at odds.

To answer the title:

If the jQuery object was created with a selector, then `name.selector` should do the trick.

To answer the body:

```
name.attr('id')
```

Comment: Seriously? `var name = $('#contactName'); name.attr('id');` is *exactly* the same as `$('#contactName').attr('id')`. If that's what you wanted, you had the answer when @benlumley replied. If you want answers, you should perhaps learn how to recognize when you get one.

Comment: No that was not what I was after.

Answer (score -3):

Don't you just use

var name= $("#contactName").val()

??

Comment: -1 The `val` function returns the value of the `value` attribute, e.g., the text in a textbox input. The OP is looking for information found within the selector that was used to create the jQuery object.